# Find and replace in a loop using macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets. Sheet 1 contains the following data

**Sheet 1:**

```
Column 1  column 2 
Hotel A   New York 
Hotel B   Melbourne
```

And I wish to replace the value in sheet 2 with this value

**Sheet 2 is like that :**

```
Column 1    Column 2   Column 3

Name        ....        .....
.....       ....        City 
....        ....        ....
Name        ....        .....
....        .....       City
```

My ideal output will be :

```
Column1     Column 2    Column 3

Hotel A     ....        .....
.....       ....        New York 
....        ....        ....
Hotel B     ....        .....
....        ....        Melbourne
```

So, I wish to go through a loop in `sheet 1` and read the name and city of hotels and go to `sheet 2` and find the words `Name` and `City` and replace them with what I read in `sheet 1`. I'm very new in VBA and started my code like that and it even goes to loop. Why is it so?

```
Sub testLoopPaste()
   Dim j, k, L, b As String
   Dim i As Long
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim sht1 As Worksheet
   Dim sht2 As Worksheet

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

   j = "Name"
   b = "City" 

   For i = 1 To 2

    k = sht1.Range("A" & i)
    L = sht1.Range("B" & i)

    sht2.Cells.Replace what:=j, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
    sht2.Cells.Replace what:=b, replacement:=L, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False

  Next i

 End Sub
```

Any tips or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: How would you known when `Name` is `Hotel A` or `Hotel B` ??

Comment: @RobinMackenzie  The first `Name` in `sheet 2` is `hotel A` because it is the first row in `Sheet 1` and the second `Name` is `hotel B` because it is the second row in `sheet 1`.  In other words, The number of `Name` in `Sheet 2` is equal to the number of rows in `sheet 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cells.Replace` will change **all** occurrences of `What` with `Replacement`.

You need to `Find` the cell you are looking for, and then replace the value in just that cell:

```
Sub testLoopPaste()
    'Note: existing code was declaring j, k and L as Variant
    Dim j As String, k As String, L As String, b As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim found As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    j = "Name"
    b = "City" 

    For i = 1 To 2
        ' always advisable to specify .Value rather than assuming it will be the default property    
        k = sht1.Range("A" & i).Value
        L = sht1.Range("B" & i).Value

        Set found = sht2.Cells.Find(What:=j, _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                    After:=sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, sht2.Cells.Count), _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False, _
                                    SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            found.Value = k
        End If

        Set found = sht2.Cells.Find(What:=b, _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                    After:=sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, sht2.Cells.Count), _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False, _
                                    SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            found.Value = L
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I tested the code. Hotel A and Hotel B end up in reversed positions. The cities are correct.

Comment: @June7 - I was worried about that - I was hoping that you would have headings in the first row and therefore the first match wouldn't be in cell A1.  Give me a few minutes and I will update the answer to start the search at Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).

Comment: @June7 - OK - I have forced the `Find` to start from the very last cell on the sheet.  That way, if the first match is in cell A1, it will still find it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  The loop searches for each Name and City in sht1 and replaces the first occurrence in columns "A" and "C" of sht2:

```
Sub testLoopPaste()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

  Dim Loc As Range
  For i = 1 To sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
   Set Loc = sht2.Columns(1).Find(What:="Name")
   If Not Loc Is Nothing Then Loc.Value = sht1.Cells(i, "A")
   Set Loc = sht2.Columns(3).Find(What:="City")
   If Not Loc Is Nothing Then Loc.Value = sht1.Cells(i, "B")
  Next i

End Sub
```